# Sampling from the posterior with a constraint on the posterior mean

Tags: bayesian, simulation, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, metropolis-hastings

### **Background**

Under certain assumptions we know that being given the posterior mean and a family of conditional distributions, we can uniquely determine the joint distribution. I quote one of the theorems specifying appropriate conditions below. The theorem comes from [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b97592) and provides the conditions for power series distributions $X|Y \sim PSD(Y)$.

> **Theorem 7.2**
> Let $(X,Y)$ be a random vector such that either:
> (a) $S(X) = \{0,1,2,...,n\}$ for some integer $n$ and the cardinality of $S(Y)$ is $\leq n+2$; or
> (b) $S(X)= \{0,1,2,...\}$ and $S(Y) \subseteq \{0,1,2,...\}$.
>
> Assume that the supports $S(X)$ and $S(Y)$ are known and that for any $x \in S(X), y\in S(Y)$ we have
> $$P(X=x|Y=y) = c(x)y^x/c^*(y),$$
> where $c$ and $c^*$ are known. In addition, if $S(Y)$ is not bounded assume that
> $$\sum_{x \in S(X)} \sqrt[2x]{c(x)} = \infty.$$
> Then the distribution of $(X,Y)$ is uniquely determined by $\mathbb{E}(Y|X=x) = \psi(x), x\in S(x)$.

### **Example**

Let $X|Y=y \sim Pois(\lambda y)$. Then $X|Y \sim PSD(Y)$ with $c(x) = \lambda^x/x!$ and $c^*(y) = \exp(\lambda y)$. $\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \sqrt[2x]{c(x)} \geq \sqrt{\lambda} \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} = \infty$, so the conditional expectation of $Y$ given $X$ uniquely determines the joint distribution.

We don't know anything about the joint distribution other than it exists and is unique. The proof is not constructive. I would like to find $Y|X$ by simulation methods.

In general let's assume we have the following setting - tractable likelihood $X|\theta$ and the functional form of the posterior mean $\mathbb{E}(\theta|X) = \phi(X)$.

### **Question**

Is it possible to simulate observations from the posterior and utilize the information about the posterior mean in an MCMC setting?

Comment: "I would like to find | by simulation methods" How can you perform these simulations if you do not know the distribution of Y in your example? What are you gonna simulate? Or do you want to estimate Y|X given some sample of data?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Well, that's the question. I do not know the distribution of $Y$ but I know that it is unique as per the theorem and knowing the distribution of $X|Y$ and the functional form of $\mathbb{E}(Y|X) = \phi(X)$ is enough to find it.

Answer (score 2):

Given that both $X$ and $Y$ are integer valued, e.g. with a finite number of values, a likely trick in deriving the marginals of $X$ and $Y$ stands in writing enough linear relations between $\mathbb P(X=x)$ and $\mathbb P(Y=y)$ to identify the marginals. (After writing the derivation below, I checked [the referenced book](https://amzn.to/3HbY1Ed) and found out that the authors reach the same conclusion in eqn (7.38).)

For instance, assume that $S(X) =S(Y) = \{0,1,2,...,n\}$. Then, for $0\le \imath,\jmath\le n$,
$$ \mathbb P(Y=\jmath|X=\imath) = \frac{\mathbb P(X=\imath|Y=\jmath)\mathbb P(Y=\jmath)}{\mathbb P(X=\imath)}=\frac{\jmath^\imath c(\imath)/c^*(\jmath)\overbrace{\mathbb P(Y=\jmath)}^{q(\jmath)}}{\underbrace{\mathbb P(X=\imath)}_{p(\imath)}}$$ Therefore, for $0\le \imath\le n$,
$$\psi(\imath) = \sum_{\jmath=0}^n \jmath\mathbb P(Y=\jmath|X=\imath)=\sum_{\jmath=0}^n \jmath^{\imath+1} \frac{c(\imath)q(\jmath)}{c^*(\jmath)p(\imath)} = \frac{c(\imath)}{p(\imath)} \sum_{\jmath=0}^n \jmath^{\imath+1} \frac{q(\jmath)}{c^*(\jmath)}$$
or
$$p(\imath)\frac{\psi(\imath)}{c(\imath)}=\sum_{\jmath=0}^n \jmath^{\imath+1} \frac{q(\jmath)}{c^*(\jmath)}\tag{1}$$
Furthermore,
$$p(\imath)=\sum_{\jmath=0}^n \mathbb P(X=\imath|Y=\jmath) \mathbb P(Y=\jmath)=\sum_{\jmath=0}^n \frac{\jmath^\imath c(\imath)}{c^*(\jmath)}q(\jmath)\tag{2}$$
Hence, merging (1) and (2),
$$\sum_{\jmath=0}^n \frac{\jmath^\imath c(\imath)}{c^*(\jmath)}q(j)\frac{\psi(\imath)}{c(\imath)}=\sum_{\jmath=0}^n \jmath^{i+1} \frac{q(\jmath)}{c^*(\jmath)}$$
or
$$\sum_{\jmath=0}^n \frac{\jmath^\imath q(\jmath)\psi(\imath)}{c^*(\jmath)}=\sum_{\jmath=0}^n \jmath^{i+1} \frac{q(\jmath)}{c^*(\jmath)}$$
or again
$$\sum_{\jmath=0}^n \left\{{\psi(\imath)}-{\jmath}\right\}\frac{\jmath^\imath}{c^*(\jmath)}q(\jmath)=0\tag{3}$$
which leads to a system of $n+1$ equations in $\mathbf q=(q(0),\ldots,q(n))$ and, along with the normalisation constraint
$$\sum_{\jmath=0}^n q(\jmath)=1$$
it should lead to a unique derivation of the marginal distribution of $Y$.

Now, this does not directly answer the question about an MCMC resolution since solving (3) produces a marginal distribution and hence a way to directly simulate from the joint. (An unsubstantiated suggestion is to move $\mathbf q$ at each MCMC iteration by one gradient descent step when starting from a arbitrary value.)